# Send request by ajax and want to display rails errors in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to post my data via ajax instead of the rails form submit.
But when I want to get the errors, it seems to have difficulty to pass the message.
Here are my code:

In model:

```
    validates_uniqueness_of :record, :message => " should be between 0 to 5"
```

In controller:

```
    def new
        @calculator = Calculator.new
        puts "from new #{@test}"
    end

    def create
        @calculator = Calculator.new(params[:calculator])
        if @calculator.save 
            puts "success"
        else
            @test = @calculator.errors[:record]
            puts @test
            render :action => :new
        end     
    end
```

In views:

```
    <% if @calculator.errors.any? %>
        <%= @calculator.errors.full_messages %>
    <% end %>
```

" should be between 0 to 5"(from create) shows in terminal, but the "from new #{@test}"(from new) doesn't show the message.

It works fine if @test is saved to flash[:notice]. But I want to know if this problem is because the error message can only be bind to form fields?
Or is there any wrong with my code?
Thanks

Comment: because you don't define `@test` variable on new method, so `@test` is nil. When `@calculator` is not saved, it renders new view, but code in new method is not run.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your ajax code.

But, from I understood. You want to create new calculator by ajax? If save successfully, show flash[:notice], if save wrong, show flash[:error]

The ajax work without reload page. It means your code `render :action => :new` is not necessary.

On your controller:

```
def create
  @calculator = Calculator.new(params[:calculator])
  if @calculator.save 
    msg = "Create successfully"
  else
    msg = @calculator.errors[:full_messages]
  end     

  if request.xhr?
    response_to |format|
      format.json{msg: msg}
    end
  end
end
```

Now on you ajax code, on response `success`. The response must be have `response["msg"]`

All you need now is show msg from response